# Specify location of static libraries for C++ application in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, static-libraries, codeblocks

first of all, I hope that I ask the question in the right context here...

I build an application in C++ with Code::Blocks. The application uses static libraries that are provided by a third party and cannot be installed on a system via the package management. Therefore I ship these libraries when I distribute my application.

Here is what my target configuration looks like:

```
<Target title="Unix_162">
<Option output="bin/my_app" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
<Option working_dir="/home/marco/third_party_dist/lib" />
<Option object_output="obj/Unix_162" />
<Option type="1" />
<Option compiler="gcc" />
<Option use_console_runner="0" />
<Option parameters="-c" />
<Compiler>
<Add directory="/home/marco/third_party_dist/include" />
</Compiler>
<Linker>
<Add library="/home/marco/third_party_dist/lib/lib1.so" />
<Add library="/home/marco/third_party_dist/lib/lib2.so" />
<!-- some more included the same way -->
<Add directory="/home/marco/third_party_dist/lib" />
</Linker>
</Target>
```

I can build this target fine and run it. Everything works.

Today, I tried to run in on Debian Squeeze and just copied a folder which contained both the executable and the libraries from the third party. I thought that as long as everything is in one folder the executable will find the .so files. I was wrong. I get the message:

```
/home/my_app/my_app: error while loading shared libraries: lib1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I don't get this message on my developement machine because Code::Blocks is able to set a working directory for the executable. I could remove the error message by putting the location of the .so files inside /etc/ld.so.conf.d/my_app.conf...

Is there anyway I can build the executable so it searches the libs in the execution directory? Or this is a problem specific for Debian? Or can I specify the working directory for the process before I execute the executable?

I want to avoid changing the systems configuration / environment before you can start the application...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point these are not static libraries (they are shared).

So the problem is locating the libraries at runtime.
There are a couple of ways of doing this:

1) set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.
This is like PATH but for shared libraries.

2) set the rpath in the executable.
This is a path backed into the executable where is searches for shared libs

```
-Wl,-rpath,<LIB_INSTALL_PATH>
```

This can be set to `.`  which will make it look in the current directory.
or you can set to `'$ORIGIN'` which will make it look in the directory the application is installed in.

3) You can install them into one of the default locations for shared libraries.
Look inside `/etc/ld.so.conf` but usually `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib`

4) You can add more default locations
Modify `/etc/ld.so.conf`

Comment: Solution 2) sounds good for me. I don't get where to put these parameters right now. Do I have to put them into "Other linker options", do I pass them at runtime / before execution?

Comment: You pass them at link time. It assumes you are using g++/gcc to link the applications.

Comment: Thanks alot!! I passed the arguments in the "Other linker options" textfield in Code::Blocks and assume that this is then done at link time. I copied the app to the debian system and it started just fine!

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin: No I got it correct. But `'$ORIGIN'` is probably better but is slightly different from `.`. as '.' means the current working directory while `'$ORIGIN'` is the directory where the application is installed.

Comment: Having `.` in rpath is kind of useless: now the user has to run the application from a certain directory only. From security perspective it is probably as bad as having `.` in `PATH`. Anyway, you listed many ways to adjust linker search paths but none of them was the right answer until you copied mine. Hence the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is, you have to pass option `-rpath <path>` to your linker where `<path>` is the path of your library (similar to option `-L`).

Also, you are probably talking about *shared* libraries, not *static* ones.

Comment: Can this <path> be relative to the executable? Or the working directory?

Comment: This is what happens when I pass the parameter: g++: error: unrecognized option ‘-R’

Comment: Hmm, g++: error: unrecognized option ‘-rpath’. Maybe I do something wrong... But I can't find -R or -rpath in the g++ manpage...

Comment: All I have are these .so files... How can I find out whether these are shared or static?

Comment: @Marco: `.so` files are shared, the extension means "shared object".  Static libraries are usually `.a` on linux.

Answer (score -1):

> I thought that as long as everything is in one folder the executable will find the .so files. I was wrong.

An extra step is required to make Linux dynamic linker look for shared libraries in the same directory as the executable. Link the executable with `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'` option (in the makefile `$` needs to be quoted like `-Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN'`). See [$ORIGIN and rpath note](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) for more details.